# What is the most idiomatic (or the fastest) way to sum up a list in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Here is what I would implement

**functional way**

```
let sum l = List.fold_left (fun s x -> s+x) 0 l
```

**imperative way**

```
let sum l =
  let sum = ref 0 in
  List.iter (fun x -> sum := !sum +x) l;
  !sum
```

---

Is there even a better/faster way to do it?

I asked this because the book [Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/beta3/en/html/a-guided-tour.html#refs) says:

```
# let sum list =
    let sum = ref 0 in
    List.iter list ~f:(fun x -> sum := !sum + x);
    !sum
  ;;
val sum : int list -> int = <fun>
```

`This isn't the most idiomatic (or the fastest) way to sum up a list, but it shows how you can use a ref in place of a mutable variable.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is slightly cooler ;)

```
let sum l = List.fold_left (+) 0 l;;
```

To see performance:

```
open Printf

let sum1 l = List.fold_left (fun s x -> s+x) 0 l;;
let sum2 l = List.fold_left (+) 0 l;;
let sum3 = List.fold_left (+) 0;;

let rec make_list x acc = function
| 0 -> acc
| n -> make_list x (x :: acc) (n-1)

let l = make_list 1 [] 50000000;;

let _ = match Sys.argv.(1) with
| "1" -> printf "%d\n" (sum1 l)
| "2" -> printf "%d\n" (sum2 l)
| "3" -> printf "%d\n" (sum3 l)
| _ -> printf "Bad arg\n"
;;
```

Giving

```
$ ocamlc foo.ml
$ time ./a.out 1
50000000

real    0m8.204s
user    0m7.211s
sys 0m0.848s
$ time ./a.out 2
time ./a.out 3
50000000

real    0m8.226s
user    0m7.325s
sys 0m0.818s
$ 50000000

real    0m8.472s
user    0m7.561s
sys 0m0.837s
```

sum1 and sum2 have exactly the same bytecode:

```
    branch L2
    restart
L3: grab 1
    acc 1
    push
    acc 1
    addint
    return 2
L1: acc 0
    push
    const 0
    push
    closure L3, 0
    push
    getglobal List!
    getfield 14
    appterm 3, 4
L2: closure L1, 0
    push
    acc 0
    makeblock 1, 0
    pop 1
    setglobal Foo1!
```

sum3 has smaller bytecode but is slower

```
    branch L2
    restart
L1: grab 1
    acc 1
    push
    acc 1
    addint
    return 2
L2: const 0
    push
    closure L1, 0
    push
    getglobal List!
    getfield 14
    apply 2
    push
    acc 0
    makeblock 1, 0
    pop 1
    setglobal Foo3!
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0 ;;

Comment: No, it is not faster.  They generate the exact same bytecode.  Though both are faster than @stonemetal's eta-contracted version :)

Comment: to answer your question in your answer, I think it is because `sum3 is a partial function`, and in `Real World OCaml, Chapter 2`, it says "You might worry that curried functions are terribly expensive, but this is not the case. In OCaml, there is no penalty for calling a curried function with all of its arguments. **(Partial application, unsurprisingly, does have a small extra cost.)**". Of course, I don't know whether I am correct or not.

Answer (score 3):

Using Batteries:

```
let sum = BatList.reduce (+)
```

(actually, Batteries already have BatList.sum function which does exactly what you want - so no need to write it :)

Comment: I prefer the fold version over this one since it will throw an exception on an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative the author had in mind may have been to manually write the fold:

```
let low_level_sum list =
  let rec loop sum = function
    | [] -> sum
    | x::xs -> loop (sum + x) xs in
  loop 0 list
```

This is ugly and low level, and you should prefer `List.fold_left (+) 0` unless you have a concrete performance concern. (And possibly even then - the OCaml compiler's inlining of recursive functions is being worked on and there may not be a performance advantage.)